# Google Playstore - "Downloading a large app" with APKExpansion File

Tags: android, google-play, apk-expansion-files

I have an Android App which has a size of 90 MB in total whereas the expansion file is 76 and the real app only 13 MB.
Whenever downloading the App from the Android market for the first time it gives a popup saying "Downloading a large app".

Does anyone know up from which file size the Google PlayStore is showing this popup or is this just shown by default because I am using an APK expansion file?

Best regards
tsemann

Answer (score 1):

when you download the app from google play, it will also download the APK expansion pack together with the stripped APK. Thus this will make google play show popup that you are downloading a large app. Also, if you look on the app size in google play store you will see that the size is the total of APK + expansion file.